# GraphQl API select specific values

Tags: graphql

I have the following query :

```
{
  allPeople {
    people {
      name
      filmConnection {
        films {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to select all people that have a film connection with the title a new hope. How do i select this specific thing from the API. I could also just get it like this and handle it in the code. But surely there is a better way.

What i'd expect :

```
{
  allPeople {
    people {
      name
      filmConnection {
        films {
          title : "a new hope"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That didnt work..

Try out here in this playground :

https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql?query=%7B%0A%20%20allPeople%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20people%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20filmConnection%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20films%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20title%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A

Comment: This `graphql` API doesn't allow passing arguments to the `title` field, so you can't do that.

Comment: @goto1 how would i do this in a case like this normally

Comment: just like you suggested, you'd have to handle it in your code.

Comment: @goto1 thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## graphql queries ... are not for building [sql] queries ;)

### this is more for defining shape of required data

parameter **CAN BE passed to deeper child** (f.e. can be used to filter films)

```
{
  allPeople {
    people {
      name {
        filmConnection {    
          films(title_eq:"a new hope") { 
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... **if API supports this kind of filtering** for `films`

... but **it won't filter people** - you'll have **all people AND filtered films** (for all people) because filters won't work on parents.

You **CAN have custom API** that will be this kind of filtering aware, f.e.

```
{
  allPeople {
    people(connectedFilmTitle_eq:"a new hope") {
      name {
        filmConnection {    
          films { 
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

customized (not automatically gnerated) `peolpe` resolver can make appriopriate query [on joined tables] and return structure you're asking for.

In that case probably you don't need deeper structures - `...filmConnection { films { title` - you know this data earlier (filter parameters).

... **but probably you have a many2many relation and cen reverse this query**:

```
{
  allFilms {
    films(title_eq:"a new hope") {
      title {
        peoleConnection {    
          people { 
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but isnt films a parent , how come you can have a parameter here?

Comment: it's about general graphql possibilities and rules - not this particular API